# Bigquery - aggregate while filtering out values

Tags: google-bigquery

I'm sure this question has been answered elsewhere but I can't find it.

I have a table of invoices like

| id | company | index | date_sent | amount |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Com1 | 1 | 2022-01-01 | 100 |
| 2 | Com1 | 2 | 2022-02-01 | 100 |
| 3 | Com1 | 3 | 2022-03-01 | 100 |
| 4 | Com1 | 4 | 2022-04-01 | 100 |
| 5 | Com2 | 1 | 2022-02-01 | 100 |
| 6 | Com2 | 2 | 2022-03-01 | 100 |
| 7 | Com2 | 3 | 2022-04-01 | 100 |
| 8 | Com3 | 1 | 2022-01-01 | 100 |
| 9 | Com3 | 2 | 2022-02-01 | 100 |
| 10 | Com4 | 1 | 2022-01-01 | 100 |

(Index here is added by basically doing `RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY co ORDER BY date_sent) as index`)

I'd like to return companies who have more than 3 invoices, the aggregate sum of those 3 invoices and the date sent of the 3rd invoice.

For example, for the data above, the returned data should be:

| company | date_3rd | amount_sum_3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Com1 | 2022-03-01 | 300 |
| Com2 | 2022-04-01 | 300 |

So far I've got:

```
select company,
  (select sum(amount) from grouped_invs.amount_sum_3 amount) as amount_sum_3,
from (
  select company,
    array_agg(invoices.amount order by invoices.index limit 3) amount_sum_3,
  from `data` invoices
  group by invoices.company
  having count(*) => 3
) grouped_invs
```

which gives me

| company | amount_sum_3 |
| --- | --- |
| Com1 | 300 |
| Com2 | 300 |

But I can't figure out how to get the 3rd date sent out from there.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might consider below

```sql
SELECT (SELECT AS STRUCT
          ANY_VALUE(company) AS company,
          MAX(date_sent) date_3rd,
          SUM(amount) amount_sum_3
        FROM grouped_invs.amount_sum_3).*
  FROM (
    SELECT ARRAY_AGG(invoices ORDER BY index LIMIT 3) amount_sum_3
      FROM `data` invoices
     GROUP BY invoices.company HAVING COUNT(*) >= 3
  ) grouped_invs;
```

Assuming that your data already has an `index`, below will return same results.

```sql
SELECT company, MAX(date_sent) date_3rd, SUM(amount) amount_sum_3 
  FROM (
    SELECT * FROM `data` invoices
     WHERE index <= 3
   QUALIFY COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY company) >= 3
  )
 GROUP BY 1;
```

**Query results**

[image]